# (Free?) Hosting Control Panels

Tags: linux

I've installed and used both **[cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/)** and **[Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/)** on my dedicated servers in the past and I truly enjoyed the [features and simplicity of cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/features.html) (specially the auto-update feature in **WHM**), recently (a couple of months ago) I also tried a beta version of the open-source **[OpenPanel](http://www.openpanel.com/)** and although it looks really nice I found it kinda limited in terms of features, such as automatic system updates, automatic backups and the ability to add addicional hosts to the MySQL allowed clients list - just to name a few.

[OpenPanel http://www.openpanel.com/images/screenshot1_thumb.png](http://www.openpanel.com/images/screenshot1_thumb.png)

Besides **OpenPanel**, I'm aware of **[Usermin](http://www.webmin.com/usermin.html)**, **[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)**, **[Virtualmin](http://www.virtualmin.com/)**, **[ISPConfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/)**, **[VHCS](http://vhcs.net/)**, **[web-cp](http://www.web-cp.net/)** and **[FlexCP](http://flexcp.sourceforge.net/)** - although I've never had the opportunity to try any of them before... Are you familiar and recommend any of these?

It's been a while since I managed a dedicated server and I'm wondering what would be a good hosting control panel for me, preferably a free / open-source one that has similar features / usability of **cPanel**.

I appreciate all input, thanks! =)

Comment: You're advertising OpenPanel over there, did you make your choice already? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/37801#37801

Comment: @Tobu: I'm more inclined to it, yes. I just though it would be a good idea to spread the word a little, maybe by doing so the quality and features of OpenPanel will improve. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at DirectAdmin.

Comment: DA is not free.

Comment: They only said "preferably a free / open-source one".

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.isp-control.net/

Not bad, and development isn't stale!

Answer (score 1):

Not tried myself, and avaliable as debian/ubuntu packages, dtc:

http://www.gplhost.com/software-dtc.html

Baifox is another option, not as complete as plesk/cpanel:

http://www.baifox.org/